# Bookmarks API on Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, firefox

Are there any API on Firefox to retrieve the users' bookmarks with javascript ?

thanks,

Bruno

Comment: Are talking about a plugin or a normal website context?

Comment: @ ZeissS A plugin because I need the user's approval (if you know a solution without a plugin I'm interested though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For firefox , you can use bookmark service in javascript via XPConnect. But these code may give user warning as the result of the privilege reason.

For more information about the code, you can refer to the online documents here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Bookmarks

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Do you know something similar with Internet Explorer ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have experience in IE developments. Hope other guys can help you :D

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't expose Javascript APIs for access to Favorites.  You can write Win32 code to enumerate the shortcut files in the [favorites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911%28VS.85%29.aspx) [folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28VS.85%29.aspx) and then use the appropriate [COM goo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776784%28VS.85%29.aspx) to crack open the data in the .url files themselves.